# How do you setup Ekiga

Tags: ekiga

When I try to set up Ekiga, I keep getting error messages saying it can't register both my Ekiga account and my diamondcard account, which I use for the SIP account. I'm pretty sure I've got all the info for both accounts entered correctly. Does anybody know what the problem might be? Thank you much.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here, blended with the information from your DiamondCard account ?

http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Manual

Comment: Yes, I did that. Could it be that I haven't used my diamondcard account for over 3 years? However, when I go to the Diamondcard page, I can access call history, etc. Maybe my balance of $7 is too low. It seems like their support is non funcional. Their chat window is always off line, and I get a message, when calling by phone, saying that no one is available.

Comment: I was able to get a Ekiga Call Out account using the Configuration Assistant, but I can't get it to be registered.   Also, since I opened that account, I started getting repeated calls form "1001," whatever that is. I can hear it ring, and when I accept the call, it says connected, but I also get a missed call message. The only way I could get the calls to stop was to exit Ekiga. Got any ideas?